# AWS S3 - java.net.UnknownHostException: repo-user-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-sdk, spring-cloud

I have a service that uses S3 to upload images. When a Run it locally(running only the services's jar in Windows), it works OK.
But using docker compose with other services, when I try to upload a image I get this error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: repo-user-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo-user-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com                                                                                                                           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

The yml file for the docker compose looks like:

```
version: '2'

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.6.26
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  eureka-service:
    image: services/eureka-server
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"


  image-service:
    image: services/image-service
    ports:
      - "8060:8060"
    links:
      - mysqldb
      - eureka-service
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=compose
```

The configuraton for the profile compose are:

```
server.port:8060
spring.application.name=imageService

spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://localhost/db
spring.datasource.username:user
spring.datasource.password:password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

cloud.aws.region.static:us-west-2
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey:accessKey
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey:secretKey
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
cloud.aws.region.auto=true
s3.bucket.name.photos.profiles:repo-user-bucket

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://192.168.99.100:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds=5
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds=5
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=5
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=5
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The general reason for this error is a DNS lookup failure.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: repo-user-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

**The background**

The HTTP client that runs the AWS API calls under the hood of the AWS SDK, needs to lookup the DNS entry of the S3 bucket in order to establish a TCP connection, to run the requested S3 operation. This kind of a DNS failure can happen once in a while as a transient network error and that should be anticipated and mitigated with retries. Some amount of the retry mechanism is built into the underlying HTTP client library. The problem is when this is a persistent error.

**The problem in our case**

When we ran into this problem, upon investigation we realized that the code that was throwing this error was running in AWS Lambda, and the Security Group attached to the Lambda function, did not have any Egress Rules setup. So all DNS requests for looking up the S3 DNS entry were getting dropped at the VPC boundary. After adding the Egress Rules to permit outbound traffic the problem got resolved.

**Possible problem in your case**

The problem in your case could be similarly related to the outbound network routing and blocking. Things to check could be

- The network config for docker compose
- The ECS Cluster setup and EC2 host configuration
- The VPC setup

**Other alternatives**

If it is intended to keep outbound traffic restricted for tighter compliance, then an alternative is to setup [VPC Gateway Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) for required AWS services.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too and in the morning got resolved on its own maybe aws server was itself down something like that.